# evaluate: $ \oint_c w \frac{d}{dw} \left( \frac{\phi (w)^n}{(w-a)^n}\right) dw$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $\phi(w) $ is analytic in the circle with center $a$ then how to evaluate the integral?
$$ \oint_c w \frac{d}{dw} \left( \frac{(\phi (w))^n}{(w-a)^n}\right) dw$$

[image]

In second last line of the above picture, I don't understand how it is evaluated. Can anyone explain? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I solved the problem you originally posted.  Please think hard before making such changes to your problem, as people are likely working hard on your original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write

$$\frac{d}{dw} \left [\frac{\phi(w)}{w-a} \right ]^n = n \left [\frac{\phi(w)}{w-a} \right ]^{n-1} \left [\frac{\phi'(w)}{w-a} - \frac{\phi(w)}{(w-a)^2}\right] = n [\phi(w)]^{n-1} \left [\frac{\phi'(w)}{(w-a)^n} - \frac{\phi(w)}{(w-a)^{n+1}} \right ]$$

The integral is then

$$\oint_C dw \, w \frac{d}{dw} \left( \frac{(\phi (w))^n}{(w-a)^n}\right) = i 2 \pi a n! \left [\frac{d^n}{dw^n} [\phi(w)^{n-1} \phi'(w)] \right ]_{w=a} \\+ i 2 \pi a n \cdot n! \left [\frac{d^{n+1}}{dw^{n+1}} \phi(w)^n  \right ]_{w=a}$$

Comment: ok ok thank you!! how does first term vanish?? I mean could we make it vanish??

Comment: If $\phi$ is linear, then both terms will vanish.  If $\phi'(a)=0$, then the first term vanishes.  Otherwise, not sure.

Comment: thanks anyway, i found the more generalized proof [here](http://books.google.com.np/books?id=d4a99Fls3CcC&pg=PA14&dq=lagrange+expansion+proof&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6M1xUePyCIXRrQebg4GIAg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=lagrange%20expansion%20proof&f=false)